# How to get 2 data-points with one name in series Line Graph Highcharts Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want the following output with Highcharts [image]

I want a drop down Selector which will have the values from database with the latest entry at the beginning. And a series selector with 2 data for example

```
series:{
   name: "Xyz",
   data1: [],
   data2: []
}
```

The data is dynamic and is in JSON format . And want to change the visibility of the series by keeping one true and others false.
Can someone please help me to get the above image as an output?
Thank you :)

Comment: The output which you want to achieve is something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/ but I don't get it how do you want to render the chart. Would you like to show it on the button with downloaded data from server? Could you describe it more precisiely?

Comment: Hey @SebastianWędzel , I need a 2 lines to be visible with one name , like as in the output of the image : On clicking on series 1 , I want the blue as well as the black line visible together ! How can I achieve it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for more details. You will achieve your requirements by using the **linkedTo** feature.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y1ma6svo/

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}, {
        linkedTo: ':previous',
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo